# How do you build a node project into one file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, require

I have been creating projects using npm. For AMD I am using the native node require because it is convenient and does what I need it to do.  To run my projects at the moment I am using grunt-watchify.  This allows me to point a file of entry and a file of output.  So at the moment it produces one file uncompressed or mangled.

I would like to know what is the best approach for compressing and mangling my final file.  I have tried uglify after the file is built by watchify but it does not seem to work correctly.  I feel that is a dirty hack anyway.  So here is my questions?

What is the best way to build a node project into one file?  Grunt library suggestions would be great.  Any that support compression/minifying would also be great.

Thanks

Comment: when you say a 'node project', do you mean the client side assets of a website *served* by node ? ( eg not node app server code )

Comment: Why would you want your project in a single file?

Comment: Here are the favs - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat ( merge files ) - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin ( minify css ) - and the uglify you have said .

Comment: Client side javascript project.  Serving the project on static web server.  Now, what grunt-watchify does is put the require source in the single file so so the require function can work.

Comment: problem was solved by using grunt-browserify and grunt-contrib-uglify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed my dependency on grunt-watchify and now just use grunt-browersify and grunt-contrib-watch.  I then use grunt-contrib-uglify and grunt-contrib-cssmin to minimize files afterwards.